# Found newborn puppy on the street. What should I do?

Tags: dogs, pest-control, new-pets

My friends and I found a newborn puppy and have temporarily made a shelter for him in the park. It is an old sink covered with an asbestos sheet. Till the time we manage to find a home for it, what are the preliminary steps to be taken?

**Age**: we don't really know its age, but I can give you some info which will help you deduce it's age:

- Its eyes are open.
- It only drinks milk. Refuses to eat biscuits or bread.
- It is light enough for me to pick up with one hand (I'm fourteen).
- It is about 10 inches (25 cm) in length.

I also noticed that it is covered with a lot of tiny bugs and attracts a lot of flies... Anything that can be done about this?

PS: The only reason it isn't already living with me is because my mom won't allow it...

Comment: How do you know it's mother wasn't going to come back for it?

Comment: Is an animal rescue or shelter an option?

Comment: @JamesJenkins not really an option here in India... Good ones can be pretty hard to find :(

Comment: @keshlam because we watched it roam around alone  for the whole afternoon and evening... Plus, the temporary home we made for it was in the park adjacent to the street where we found it and it has a pretty big gate so we reckoned that it wouldn't be too difficult for the mother to find it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a difficult question. You are 14 and do not have parental approval to bring a pet into your home.  A rescue or shelter is not option in your area.

The little bugs are probably fleas, you can learn about flea control at [A stray dog has fleas. Any way to help remove them?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8163) & [How can I get rid of fleas without dangerous chemicals?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/107) some of the more effective treatments have costs.

We have a couple of questions specific to dog parasite and health issues in India; [How important is it to get your dog vaccinated for heartworm in India?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5971) & [Anti-rabies vaccination once in 3 years for pets in countries like India?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/)

There are costs as well as considerations for your health involved in caring for a dog (or any pet).  Providing care without a secure home is going to be nearly impossible.  Puppies need milk from a dog to do well, more detail at [Should I supplement the diet of a breast-feeding puppy?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/)

I think it is great that you are trying to save the puppy, but if you can't find it a home soon, it will likely suffer considerably. If it does survive and you don't find a home it will become a stray dog.

Related [Adopting Stray Dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10557)

There are several considerations, you have taken on the responsibility of caring for the abandoned puppy, the decisions about, What you should I do?, are yours.  Hopefully you will find enough information here to make informed decisions.

Comment: Thanks for the help... We're doing all that we can do and asking around in case someone wants to adopt it...

Answer (score 1):

I would say  there are possibly fleas on it, take the puppy to the vet but make sure you wear gloves or something to protect you, as the puppy could be ill or have a disease (you never know) Go to the vets and ask for treatment but also explain that you found it and you can't keep the dear, the vets might take the puppy, treat it then get ready to go to a shelter or just adopted, the size also depends on what breed the puppy is.